# Android fill_parent to match_parent

Tags: android, fill-parent

What was the reason behind introducing match_parent and deprecating fill_parent since both mean the same thing. won't this change be a hindrance to backward compatibility?

Comment: I always wondered about this too. I actually think `fill_parent` represents the meaning better than `match_parent`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using match_parent instead of fill_parent will NOT make the generated APK unrunnable in older versions because in the generated APK the occurrence of match_parent's and fill_parent's will be replaced with their corresponding Constant Value, which is same in this case (both are -1), so same APK can run on older versions of Android platform as well.

But while compiling the code if you switch to older version (version 7 or below) then you will get a compilation error (since match_parent is not defined in version 7 or below).

Answer (score 4):

Android Doc says:

> FILL_PARENT (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher), which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)
>
> fill_parent: The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding).
> This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced
> by match_parent.

So They are the same as their values are both -1. But if you worry about the backward compatibility, you can go here: [platfrom version](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)

this give you a better idea on when you should change all your fill_parent to match_parent.
as of now, it seems 50% ppl are using API Level 8 or above. So it's up to you to change it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my question was why this change was done and not how to get along with it.

Comment: I am sorry, the only reason I can come up with is FILL_PARENT may mean fill the child view to its parent view at the same size and location(x, y). But the actually meaning of FILL_PARENT is the size( either width or height) is same as the parent, not the location(x, y), so they decided to change to MATCH_PARENT for a clarification on this. But I am not the one who changed the name of this, just take a reasonable guess on it. :)