# difference between fill_parent and match_parent in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between match_parent and fill_parent property in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent-property-in-android)
>   [FILL_PARENT and MATCH_PARENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949387/fill-parent-and-match-parent)

I have go through android developer site where they give following difference :

Note: Beginning with Android 2.2 (API level 8), "fill_parent" has been renamed "match_parent" to better reflect the behavior. The reason is that if you set a view to "fill_parent" it does not expand to fill the remaining space after sibling views are considered, but instead expands to match the size of the parent view no matter what—it will overlap any sibling views.

But anyone explain with example.so that things may clear.

Comment: Oh no, not this question again! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949387/fill-parent-and-match-parent ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854717/why-did-match-parent-replace-fill-parent ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516825/is-deprecated-word-the-only-difference-between-fill-parent-and-match-parent ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608196/android-fill-parent-to-match-parent ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent-property-in-android

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They're the same thing (in API Level **8+**). Use match_parent.

`fill_parent` (renamed `MATCH_PARENT` in API Level **8** and higher), which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)

`fill_parent`: The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding). This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by `match_parent`

For Android API **1.6** to **2.1** `match_parent` will throw you an error, so use fill_parent in these cases. To support backward compatibility, it's better to use `fill_parent`

I remember that Roman Guy (Android Developer at Google) said, that they have changed the name because `"fill_parent"` was confusing for developers. As matter of the fact, `"fill_parent"` does not fill the remaining space (for that you use the weight attribute) but it takes as much space as its layout parent. That's why the new name is `"match_parent"`

Comment: They're the same thing (in API Level 8+). Use match_parent.

FILL_PARENT (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher), which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)....can u explain with example.

Comment: using `match_parent` will not throw an error no matter what version of Android you are targeting...

Comment: @ArunKumar match_parent is only a name convention that Google developer has adopted for api 8 and higher!!

Comment: so that there is no difference between them.then why google changed it?

Comment: What was wrong with `fill_parent` was that it didn't actually *fill* the parent, but instead it made it have the same dimension as the parent... or in other words, it *matched* the parent dimension.

Comment: @ArunKumar I remember that Roman Guy 5Google Devveloper)said, that they have changed the name because "fill_parent" was confusing for developers. As matter of the fact, "fill_parent" does not fill the remaining space (for that you use the weight attribute) but it takes as much space as its layout parent. That's why the new name is "match_parent"

Comment: (minus padding) what does means?child have minus padding according to parent or something else.

Comment: @ArunKumar, you are no longer asking about the difference between the two... instead you are asking about its actual behavior. The answer to your original question is that *there is no difference at all*.

Comment: @ArunKumar padding right for exemple is space between a right widget border and the right parent layout border

Comment: its fine for me.but i want to explain with two explain one is for fill_parent and another for match_parent.if u can help me.because lot of things is only writing not explain with explain.i already know these above line but i am not understand.i know it works as same.

Comment: @AlexLockwood don't forget to use the @ because in your last comments ArunKumar don't get notification of your comments, and congrats for the 10K :D

Comment: @K_Anas, `static final` constants are compiled into the byte code when the `.apk` is compiled and thus, Android will not perform a dynamic search for a value represented by `match_parent` at runtime. In fact it will know nothing about the variable `match_parent` that represented the `-1`. This is why an error isn't thrown in Android 2.1 and lower

Comment: @K_Anas, (didn't forget it that time :D). And thanks lol... but still 10,000 points more to go haha -_-

Comment: @AlexLockwood:yes you are right i want to exact behavior?

Comment: @AlexLockwood, sorry but i don't think so but this constant doesn't figure in low API version i tried it and it throws an error when declaring it in Xml

Comment: @ArunKumar, both `match_parent` and `fill_parent` will stretch the size of the view to match the same size as its parent view.

Comment: when go to before 2.2 then it throw exception.

Comment: @K_Anas, sorry I misunderstood what you meant. yes you are right... an error will be thrown because `match_parent` isn't defined in the earlier SDK versions. What I meant to say is that you can use `match_parent` in newer APIs and be certain that older devices will won't crash for not "recognizing" the value (since they are compiled into the byte code).

Comment: yes fill_parent can be used for low api and higher but match_parent is for api 2.2 and higher

Comment: @AlexLockwood yes that's right

Comment: i understand @Tanis.7x answer with explain with exmple.actually fill_parent is same as match_parent because child view is not filling space instead of it matches according to parent viewgroup.actually we should use fill_parent because it also run before 2.2.its good for us.

Answer (score 2):

Both are `static final` constants that represent the value `-1`. They are hard coded into the byte code when you compile your `.apk`, so there is no difference and are both completely compatible with all Android SDK versions.

You'll see that they both represent the same value in the documentation:

> **`public static final int FILL_PARENT`**
>
> Special value for the height or width requested by a View. FILL_PARENT
>   means that the view wants to be as big as its parent, minus the
>   parent's padding, if any. This value is deprecated starting in API
>   Level 8 and replaced by MATCH_PARENT.
>
> Constant Value: -1 (0xffffffff)
>
> **`public static final int MATCH_PARENT`**
>
> Special value for the height or width requested by
>   a View. MATCH_PARENT means that the view wants to be as big as its
>   parent, minus the parent's padding, if any. Introduced in API Level 8.
>
> Constant Value: -1 (0xffffffff)

Comment: so why google change it?there is some reason behind it.

Comment: i am agree but actually can u explain with layout.

Comment: the reason they changed it is because the android team thought `fill_parent` was a misleading name... they felt the name `match_parent` better suited its actual behavior.

Comment: What was wrong with `fill_parent` was that it didn't actually *fill* the parent, but instead it made it have the same dimension as the parent... or in other words, it *matched* the parent dimension.

Answer (score 2):

The clarification is this:

- Fill parent implies (or could imply) that multiple side-by-side views would expand to completely fill their container. Thus one might think that two views with "fill_parent" added to a parent view would both resize to 50% of the parent's size.
- Match parent is clearer, as setting a view to fill_parent actually sets the size to the container's size.

As other users stated (and as the documentation states), this is purely a change to make it more obvious what the outcome of using "fill_parent" will be.

Comment: Say you have a vertical `LinearLayout` with two added `TextViews`, each with `height: "wrap_content"` and `width: "fill_parent"`. With `fill_parent`, some may expect that the two TextViews will appear side-by-side, collectively expanding to fill the LinearLayout. In reality, those views are **matching** their parent's width, and will  stack vertically.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"/>
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: this example what i want.Thanks Tanis.7x once again.