# what is difference between fill_parent and match_parent in android

Tags: android, android-layout

```
ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

OR

```
     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

Comment: FILL_PARENT (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent-property-in-android

Answer (score 1):

**both are the same thing (in API Level 8+).**

`fill_parent`: The view should be as big as its parent

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked several times before on SO, here is a similar question: [difference between fill_parent and match_parent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237651/difference-between-fill-parent-and-match-parent-in-android)

The fill_parent tag was renamed to match_parent as of API level 8.